# Xamarin Forms and MDash videos

Tags: xamarin.forms, video-streaming

I'm looking for playing a content from `Azure Media Services` in my `Xamarin Forms` apps for `iOS`, `Android` and `UWP`.

A url is in `MDash` for example is https://azneccmediaq001-euno.streaming.media.azure.net/xxc0cf6a-55e4-4c35-975a-e047b8002xxx/PREVTrailer_2.0EN.ism/manifest

Is there a way to play this kind of video without using a webview?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried by now?

Comment: Not much so far. I saw some third party components but for now I'm creating a proof of concept. I couldn't find a way apart from webviews. For legal issues, I can't use webviews.